# Explode keywords in a term aggregation (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, aggregation

I have a index with songs information. I have a field "Artist Name(s)" where there can be multiple artists separated by a comma. I want to get the count of song by artist with a **terms aggregation** but it doesn't split my field with the comma.

Here is my query :
[query agg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duajz.png)

Here is the elasticsearch response :
[es response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwQ1h.png)

I have also set the mapping of the field like this :

- **the mapping**
  [mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpr9O.png)
- **the analyzer**
  [analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lic7q.png)

Can someone help me with this please ?

Thank you,
Antoine

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

Your analyzer is set on the `Artist name(s)` field, not the `Artist name(s).keyword` field. `keyword` fields are **never analyzed**.

So your query is almost correct, if you run it on the `Artist name(s)` field, it will work, but only if you also [enable `fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) on the text field to create buckets for the field’s analyzed terms (in which case your keyword field is useless and you can remove it). Also worth noting that enabling fielddata can significantly increase memory usage.

```
"Artist Name(s)": {
  "type": "text",
  "fielddata": "true,                         <---- add this
  "analyzer": "Artist name(s) analyzer"
}
```

A better solution to your problem is to store an array of artist names in your field instead of of comma-separated ones. That way you can leave your query on the keyword field as is and it will work.

PS: You should add code as text instead of screenshots in your question, as it will make it easier for others to search and find your thread.